# Replace class on clicking outside div

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript which essentially removes a class which has a background image on focus, i.e clicking in the input box (which has the background image).

The code is as follows:

```
$(function(){
$("#ets_gp_height").focus(function(){
if(!$(this).hasClass("minbox")) {
} else {
    $(this).removeClass("minbox");
}
});
});
```

This works well, and removes .minbox when the user clicks within the input field, however what i want to do is if the user makes no changes to the input field, it should add the class back in as per at the beginning. At the moment, once the user clicks once, the class is gone for good, i would like it to come back if the user makes no changes to the input box, so for example clicks the input field but then clicks back out again without entering anything.

Any help? Possible?

Comment: use .blur() event to do this

Comment: Thanks for responding, sorry do you have updated code in how this would work?

Comment: @user8713968 see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't want the class .minBox to be added if the user has entered a value, but only if they decided not to enter anything, or chose to erase what they had entered.

To do this, you can use the blur event and check if there's anything entered:

```
$("#ets_gp_height").blur(function()=> {
     if($(this).val().length < 1) $(this).addClass('minBox');
});
```

This will work for TABing out of the input and CLICKing out of it.

Answer (score 0):

A working example, with and without jQuery:

Note: with `onblur` solution, method is called each time the field is blured, even when the value hasn't changed. with `onchange` solution, method is called **only** when the value has changed. That why `onchange` is a better solution.

WITHOUT JQUERY

```js
function onChange(input){
  input.value.length > 0 || setClassName(input, 'minbox') ;
}
function onFocus(input){
  if(input.className == 'minbox')
  {
    input.className = '' ;
  } 
}
function setClassName(o, c){ o.className = c; }
```

```css
input.minbox {background-color:red;}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ets_gp_height" class="minbox" onchange="onChange(this)" onfocus="onFocus(this)">
```

WITH JQUERY:

```js
$(function(){

  $("#ets_gp_height").change(function(){
    $(this).val().length > 0 || $(this).addClass("minbox");
  })
  

  $("#ets_gp_height").focus(function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass("minbox")) {

  } else {
      $(this).removeClass("minbox");
  }
  });
});
```

```css
input.minbox {background-color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="ets_gp_height" class="minbox">
```

Comment: this seems to be way over complicating the issue

Comment: Complicating?… Are you sure?… It's simplier than yours: change is called only on change. In your solution, blur is called (unecessary) each time the input field is blur, even when the value is the same. ;-)

Comment: do you really think a user is going to focus and blur an input so fast and often that it'll take a performance hit?

Comment: if your rational for using the change event is that it only gets called when the value changes and blur gets called more, then yes, you're saying its about performance. my point is that you're adding an entire function AND a change event. which is more complicated.

Comment: Look at my complete example (with and without jquery) and you'll understand, I think. But your solution is great too, no offense! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("blur", "#ets_gp_height", function(){
    if($(this).val() == '') {
       $(this).addClass('minBox');
    }
});
```

This code will add class 'minBox' when ever user goes out of input field without entering any value.